# What is the second part of a movie title called?

Tags: title, terminology

For a movie like "Captain America: The First Avenger", what is the term for the phrase after the colon, i.e. "The First Avenger"? Is that called a "subtitle" or something else?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to both Wikipedia and Websters, "subtitle" is used for both the phrase after the colon, **and** the text which appears at the bottom of a movie that is in a foreign language.  So, your assumption is correct.

Thanks to Sonny Burnett for pointing that out.

Comment: Yet, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle) has it without the hyphen for both usages. Is this an AE/BE thing?

Comment: Hmm...  Even Websters has it without the hyphen.  I've always seen it with the hyphen to designate the difference.  Interesting...

Comment: > In the United States and Canada, however, these terms **do** have different meanings. "Subtitles" assume the viewer can hear but cannot understand the language or accent, or the speech is not entirely clear, so they transcribe only dialogue and some on-screen text. ... The United Kingdom, Ireland, and most other countries **do not** distinguish between subtitles and closed captions, and use "subtitles" as the general term. The equivalent of "captioning" is usually referred to as "subtitles for the hard of hearing". –[Closed captioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_captioning), Wiki

Comment: The important part would be to pluralize *subtitle*. A movie that has a subtitle, may also have subtitle**s**.

Answer (score -3):

It is called as Caption. Which represents the story of movie or differentiates the movie from same series of movies

Comment: Can you provide a source for this?

Answer (score -4):

It's called a "tagline".

Comment: No, a tagline is a short sentence describing the concept of the movie and used in marketing materials - like The Magnificent Seven's "They were 7... and they fought like 700.", or Bonnie and Clyde's "They're young, they're in love, and they kill people."

Comment: https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/best-movie-taglines/